# Algolia: restrictSearchableAttributes to particular part of query

Tags: algolia

I see in the [documentation](https://www.algolia.com/doc/javascript#search__restrict-searchable-attributes) for restrictSearchableAttributes that I can restrict a query to specific attributes, and that works fine.

However, I'd like to be able to restrict just a part of the query to that attribute the way you can with Gmail's search functionality.

For example, I want the user to be able to search for:

```
Travel from:John
```

And that would look for the word "John" only in the "from" attribute, and then it would also look for Travel across all searchable attributes.

I could make `from` a facet, and send `Travel` as the query and then `facetFilters[from:John]` but if the `from` value is "John Smith" it won't be a hit. Facets have to be perfect matches.

I would appreciate any help on this and am happy to provide more clarification where necessary.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do would be to create an index containing your users.
When the input contains a trigger string (like "from:"), you could have an autocomplete search into these and then add them to  the final query as facet.

An example of an use-case pretty similar can be found in the [Autocomplete In a Textarea](https://www.algolia.com/doc/search/autocomplete-textarea) which is implementing a twitter-like mention system.

Mixing this with a regular query you'd have done otherwise could be a fit.